# Multiple meta_key with get_pages

Tags: pages

I currently have the following code where I filter by the page template;

```
$pages = get_pages( array(
‘post_type’ => ‘page’,
‘meta_key’ => ‘_wp_page_template’,
‘meta_value’ => ‘unit.php’,
‘hierarchical’ => 0
) );
```

I would also like to sort by an ACF field so would need to add something like;

```
‘meta_key’  => ‘status’,
‘orderby’   => ‘meta_value’,
‘order’ => ‘DESC’
```

Is it possible to get both meta_key parts to work together?

Comment: Keep in mind that this query will be hideously slow/expensive. Your status post meta should really have been implemented as a custom taxonomy

Comment: Also, try to avoid the helper functions such as `get_pages` and stick to `WP_Query`, or if you must, `get_posts`, you can set the `post_type` to `page`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you can do it with `get_pages()`, but you should be able to do something like this with `get_posts()`:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'page',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'template_clause' => array(
            'key'     => '_wp_page_template',
            'value'   => 'unit.php',
            'compare' => '=', 
        ),
        'status_clause' => array(
            'key'     => 'status',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS',
        ),
        'relation' => 'AND',
    ),
    'orderby' => 'status_clause',
    'order'   => 'DESC',
);
$pages = get_posts( $args );

// Better option, per Tom J Nowell's comment on the question
$page_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I haven't tested this code, but I think it should do what you're looking for.

### References

- [`WP_Query` » Custom Field (ie, post meta) parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#custom-field-post-meta-parameters) ([`get_posts()`]
  (https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/) arguments follow the same plan as `WP_Query`)
- [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)
- [`WP_Query` improvements](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/) (includes the information on naming your clauses)